how can I write the lr_usr register in supervisor mode with C inline assembly
I have searched for the specific question how to write banked registers in inline assembly but could not find an answer so my question seems novel.
I want to write the lr_usr register in supervisor mode with an address of a function.
so,
    uint32_t syscall_exit = (uint32_t) syscall_exit;
    uint32_t registers[14] = {97,6,7,6,7,6,7,6,7,6,7,5,7,(uint32_t) idle_thread_main};
    asm("ldr SPSR, #0x10");
    asm("msr lr_usr, %0":"=r"(syscall_exit)::"lr_usr");
    asm("ldmia &registers,{r0-r12,PC}^");

However, asm("msr lr_usr, %0":"=r"(syscall_exit)::"lr_usr"); throws an error: unknown register name 'lr_usr' in 'asm'
I am unsure about the last command as well. The compiler does not say anything but I know this does not mean it is valid inline assembly. I want to load the contents of registers into r0-r12 and the last one, the function into the PC.

but I know this does not mean it is valid inline assembly - if it is assembling into an object file, then it is valid. The question is whether it is the correct assembly.  But if you have a concrete hardware/simulator you can see what it does in a debugger.

okay thanks. Do you know how to solve my problem?

@EugeneSh.: Syntactically valid and compiles without error are necessary but not sufficient to say an inline asm statement is "valid".  Most people would only say it's valid if it's free of undefined behaviour, which requires that the constraints match which registers the asm template string modifies, and that you don't do anything unsupported like modify the stack pointer (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Clobbers-and-Scratch-Registers-1).  &registers isn't a valid way to refer to a C local variable, and probably doesn't assemble even if it's a global symbol.

Also, it's not safe to assume that registers are unchanged between asm statements, and you should pretty much never use GNU C Basic Asm statements (no constraints) inside functions, because you can't tell the compiler about registers, and there's either an implicit "memory" clobber or not depending on compiler version!  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/ConvertBasicAsmToExtended  .  It's also not supported to jump outside the current function from an asm statement, so ldmia into PC is something you'd have to do in a naked function or hand-written asm.

A necessary condition is described in this Q/A.

A way that works for a wider range of ARM CPUs is ldm rN, {sp,lr}^;  The caret is a special case of ldm that allows access to these registers.  The syntax lr_usr is only for virtualization extensions and it may not be available in for example, a clobber list, etc.  Also, you use SPSR, which is implying a Cortex-M to me.  For system level questions like this, you need to be more specific about the platform/target.
